# How to implement multi files upload in IE (like picasa)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, multifile-uploader

Does anyone know how I can implement a multi files upload (like picasa web) supported on IE ? 
The well known Jquery plugin blueimp does not support multi upload in IE, so I cannot get inspiration from there...
Jquery or plain javascript would be fine.

Comment: [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will achieve with plain JS, mostly for these things Flash(yuck) is being used, for example, http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: thank you for the link! unfortunatly I guess i have no choice but to use flash...